# Determining the connectedness of $\{(x,y,\sin(x^2+y^2)) : x^2+y^2=1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This question is on my exam review sheet. It says we can use the fact that $\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ is connected.

Am I correct in saying $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x,y) = (x,y,\sin(1))$ is a continuous function that maps the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to our shifted-up circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and since the domain is connected, the domain is also connected?

Unless I'm misreading something, it seems to me that this is really trivial. But this is on the sample problems handout I received, so I'm a bit paranoid that perhaps I'm missing something..?

Comment: No, this **is** trivial.

Comment: Just in case, you could check that the question is not to prove the connectedness of $$\{(x,y,\sin(x^2+y^2)) : x^2+y^2\leqslant1\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've said is correct.  Moreover, I'd highly suspect that the person writing the question made some kind of mistake, because it's such a strange question to ask, involving $\sin(1)$ like it does.